# Where can I find documentation on the ActiveRecord find_by method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

According to the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#read), the find_by method syntax looks like this:

```
# return the first user named David
david = User.find_by(name: 'David')
```

However, I ran across code today that was using

```
david = User.find_by_name 'David'
```

I can't seem to locate any documentation on the second usage, although a friend told me recently to avoid find_by and instead use where, because find_by was being depreciated or something.  Now I am confused about what is good usage of find by, if I should be using it at all, and where to find info on the above topics.

Where can I find info on the find_by method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_by` should still work. `find_by_x` was deprecated in Rails 4.  Your friend is right about using `where`, as that's the generally-more-accepted way to do things now.